# Google Maps JavaScript API - Billing

Tags: java, google-maps, billing

Is it possible to have multiple google accounts with the same credit card linked to billing ?

I have a web application that uses Google Maps JavaScript API. As I read in the documentation, there is 200$ free credit per billing account.
Let's assume that I have that much API usage that I will use 199$ of the credit each month.

Since I have multiple environments (dev, test, production), I'm interested in the billing policy. Can I create 3 separate accounts so that I have 200$ on each of them, or that is forbidden (since I have only one credit card)?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service you shouldn't create multiple accounts or projects.

Have a look at paragraph 3.2.4 (f) of Terms of service. It reads

> *No Circumventing Fees.* Customer will not circumvent the applicable Fees. For example, Customer **will not create multiple billing accounts or Projects to avoid incurring Fees**, prevent Google from accurately calculating Customer’s Service usage levels, abuse any free Service quotas, or offer access to the Services under a “time-sharing” or “service bureau” model.

source: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/#3-license

I hope this clarifies your doubt.